# Change the linestyle of all subplots at once

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a figure with many subplots and my goal is to define the `linestyle` of all subplots at once, *not for each subplot individually*. Here is a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [2, 1, 3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].plot(values)
axs[1].plot(values)
```

I tried looping through the axes with

```
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.set_linestyle('None')
```

but this threw the error: "'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_linestyle'". I also tried

```
plt.setp(axs, linestyle=...)
```

but this threw the error: "Unknown property linestyle". Any ideas?

Comment: `linestyle` is a property of the line(s) that are plotted via `plot`, not of the axes.

Comment: Ok, this explains why my approaches did not work. But does it also point me to a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: change the Matplotlib default style settings, but do it inside a `mpl.rc_context` such that other figures are not affected.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

with mpl.rc_context():
    mpl.rcParams['lines.linestyle'] = 'None'
    values = [2, 1, 3]
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    axs[0].plot(values)
    axs[1].plot(values)
```